# GFIC Breaker keeps tripping unless another breaker is off

Tags: electrical

I am trying to find out why my outlet in the upstairs bathroom doesn't work. It seems to be the only load on a GFIC breaker in my panel. It will re-trip immediately. However if I switch off the breaker that controls the lights in that bathroom and another room, the GFIC breaker will hold and the outlet works fine. I've tried having everything off and it's the same result. I'm not an electrician but I am pretty handy. Would this be possible because of a failed device or does it mean I have a short somewhere?

Comment: Need a little more information. Are you turning off one breaker or two? Assuming you are turning off one breaker, please do an assessment of everything that breaker controls. To answer your question, it can be a bad device, bad wiring in an outlet or wall, or the GFCI itself. The concerning part here is that it sounds like you have something cross wired. So, have you replaced any lights, or outlets, or switches? Perhaps a neutral got tied to the wrong feed in a ganged circuit. Your GFCI should not be in front of the lights in a different room while it may be allowable (not an elec either)

Comment: I am turning off one Breaker in order to get the other not to trip. The breaker I have to switch off in order that the other Breaker (the GFIC Breaker) won't trip controls the fan and the lights in the bathroom with the dead outlet, and it also feeds another bathrooms lights and fan. The Breaker that is tripping only controls the first bathrooms outlet as far as I can tell. I guess what I'm asking is, is it possible for two circuits to be tied together on purpose? I would assume they shouldn't be but again I'm not an electrician.

Comment: Do any loads need to be placed on the lighting circuit to cause the GFCI breaker to trip? Or does it trip with the lighting circuit completely unloaded?

Comment: It trips completely unloaded

Comment: Is there any load whatsoever on the GFCI circuit during this?

Comment: No nothing.....

Comment: Is it a multi wire branch circuit 2 hotts sharing a neutral?

Comment: Did this start happening after you make some change to the circuit?

Answer (score 3):

### Hunting those wascally cross-wired neutral wabbits

What you have here is a case of "crossed neutrals", where either:

1. Something on the lighting circuit is wired using a neutral from the GFCI circuit, or
2. The lighting circuit and the GFCI circuit have their neutrals connected (nutted) together directly.

The former requires a load on the lighting circuit though, so as long as there isn't a hidden hardwired load on it somewhere, I think we can rule it out.  The latter *can* happen on an unloaded GFCI due to the grounded neutral detector circuit kicking in, though, as it impresses a small signal on the hot and neutral lines that the N-G fault then disturbs.

I'd check every junction box the GFCI breakered circuit uses looking closely at how the neutrals are joined in them.  The lighting neutral needs to remain separate from the GFCI neutral in all places, or else you'll get a trip.

Comment: Well that seems very possible as there has been a lot of upgrades since I have moved in. The problem is I'm not exactly sure when it stopped working because it was a spare  bathroom until recently. At least I have an idea of what to look for. I'm gonna do a little investigating tomorrow and if I don't come up with something I'll probably have to hire someone. Thanks for the help, I will post and update if I find anybting

Comment: totally agree with @ThreePhaseEel on this, its exactly what I was driving at. Has it always done this? If not, I really expect it is something you may have recently touched. Also, while unlikely, I'd check "often used" outlets and switches, especially if any are not secure to the wall. Wires could have can loose, or a nut fallen off and grounding out.